# what's wrong with this javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I think it's fairly clear what I want to do here:

```
var viewnames = {};
viewnames['region-a'] = "Region A";
viewnames['region-b'] = "Region B, partial";
viewnames['region-c'] = "Region C";

function loadView(view_name) {
    alert('view_name: ' + view_name);
    alert('viewname: ' + viewnames.view_name);
    document.getElementById("viewtitle").innerText = view_name;
}
```

But if I call this with `view_name` as `region-a` the alert says `viewnames.view_name` is undefined. What is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use `viewnames[view_name]` inside your function `loadView`

Comment: To clarify: you can't use a variable for dot accessor syntax; you have to use braces.  Thus, `viewnames[view_name]` instead of `viewnames.view_name`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to index it by name, e.g. `viewnames[view_name]`

Answer (score 0):

Access it by associative array index (`viewnames[view_name]`).  Please **DO NOT** use an `eval` construct (`eval("var tmp = viewnames." + view_name + ";")`).